macOS App Distribution Signing outside of App Store with multiple targets
So apparently I get something fundamentally wrong about signing.
I have a MacosApp which I want to distribute outside the AppStore, hence the certificate with the Developer ID Application type and a provisioning profile with that certificate (need to use this one afaik because of distribution outside of AppStore) - and it works.
The problem is, I have multiple Targets and they differ in their Bundle Identifier. That means that specific distribution provisioning profile is not gonna work on the other two targets because it references a specific bundle identifier and those other two targets don't match.
Im not too sure if all targets can have the same bundle identifier but they were generated with an extra on the end, so I accepted it and it worked during development with the dev provisioning profile.
I tried creating a wildcard identifier and create the previously mentioned type of provisioning profile with the wildcard identifier but it doesn't show up on the list. When I use different types for the AppStore the wildcard identifiers show up. Im not really sure where to go from this now, especially since this is just the step before I will try to automate it with azure DevOps build pipeline.
Does anyone have a tip or two how to handle this.

EDIT 1:
So I found out, you don't actually need to give a provisioning profile at all to the extra targets. Both the lib and the Extension targets are fine with the team and the right signing certificate. And the automated task in Azure Devops tries to force the Provisioning on all targets which then fails with an error because of the mismatch of the bundle id and because the lib doesn't even accept a provisioning profile.

EDIT 2:
I have possibly a solution now but I don't really like it. It's basically that I don't try to tell azure anything about the provisioning profile and signing, and just have the correct settings in the project. I think azure just overwrites those settings if they are provided. At the same time, when I try to notarise this archive, it doesn't work because for some reason they say my app has no hardened runtime but it has. So I guess the things I set up in the project aren't really considered?
So this is the azure task. I basically pre installed the provisioning profile and access it from here.

and this is the corresponding error.
Build description path: /Users/macdeveloper/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FilterCamExt-czfhrrfcurzwccbzpmydjiviwfga/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/FilterCamExt/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/XCBuildData/3f979159c0cf3749d2c8342b6b80b415.xcbuilddata
/Users/macdeveloper/myagent/_work/5/s/FilterCamExt.xcodeproj: error: Shared does not support provisioning profiles. Shared does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile 74d75ef6-0503-4349-bcc6-228efb5b8297 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'Shared' from project 'FilterCamExt')
/Users/macdeveloper/myagent/_work/5/s/FilterCamExt.xcodeproj: error: Provisioning profile "FilterCamExt" has app ID "com.vg.filtercam.FilterCamExt", which does not match the bundle ID "com.vg.filtercam.FilterCamExt.Extension". (in target 'Extension' from project 'FilterCamExt')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

EDIT 3:
Maybe I should try to explain the situation a bit better:
I have an App with 3 targets and all of them being manually managed in signing:

a Main target ( a small UI)
a camera system extension
a framework target

The process from within Xcode works. It works means archiving via Xcode + the following notarisation process in the organizer via Distribute App > Direct Distribution works.
Within Xcode I have following things setup:

the first two have a Sandbox and Hardened Runtime Capability
Main Target has the right Provisioning Profile chosen. The team and Signing Certificate were then automatically unmodifiable set by Xcode
the System extension has only the team and signing certificate set. Provisioning Profile is set to none. (cannot have the same provisioning profile due to different bundle identifiers. The profile doesn't even pop up in the list)
The Framework Target cannot choose a Provisioning Profile as it is a Framework target. Solely the Team and the same Developer ID Application signing certificate were chosen

Since it works with this setup, I personally think that I don't have a Certificate, neither a Provisioning Profile problem, but solely how they are applied in my approach outside of the Xcode environment through terminal commands.
Context of my current approach:
I think if the Task from Azure DevOps applies the given pre installed Provisioning Profile (as seen in the previous image) to all targets, it will and can never be successful.
My current approach is to archive without signing through the task in Azure Devops (the bottom two sections can be ignored):

and then go to the archive and apply following code signing command:
codesign --force --option runtime --deep --sign "Developer ID Application: XYZ XYZ (TEAM ID)" FilterCamExt XYZ.xcarchive
After this, when I Open the organizer and try to Notarise it through Xcode, it still says it has no hardened runtime enabled. In the referenced log (IDEDistribution.verbose.log) I get following last line:
Step failed: <IDEDistributionAnalyzeArchiveStep: 0x60000be84a40>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionMethodDeveloperIDErrorDomain Code=1 "Hardened Runtime is Not Enabled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Hardened Runtime is Not Enabled, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion="FilterCamExt.app" and "com.vg.filtercam.FilterCamExt.Extension.systemextension" must be rebuilt with support for the Hardened Runtime. Enable the Hardened Runtime capability in the project editor, test your app, rebuild your archive, and upload again.}
When I check for code sign with following command:
 codesign --verify --deep --verbose FilterCamExt\ 09.08.24,\ 13.12.xcarchive
I get these:
FilterCamExt 09.08.24, 13.12.xcarchive: valid on disk
FilterCamExt 09.08.24, 13.12.xcarchive: satisfies its Designated Requirement

From the description, it seems that this issue exists in the local development process rather than in Azure DevOps Pipeline, right?

@KevinLu-MSFT Both, I have it working for the main App target but the targets fail because of the difference of the bundle IDs

*the other targets fail.
This is the case for both environments. But the main goal is the Azure DevOps Pipeline. To do that, I first have to know how to proceed at all, because im not sure what's the right solution.

Can you share more details about the Pipeline definition and the error log?

@KevinLu-MSFT done

How do you know you have hardened runtime... Are you codesigning with -o runtime --timestamp --strict --force etc?

From the error message, the provisioing profile itself also exists issue. And the same error also shows on your local machine. You need to make sure that the project can work on your local machine, then you can move the steps to Azure Pipelines.

I have added an EDIT 3, with an updated more detailed answer. Can you have a look at it? ty

When you go to create the Bundle Identifier on developer.apple.com, you will notice that it is valid for the 6 apple platforms: iOS, iPadOS, macOS, tvOS, watchOS, visionOS. You want to use an explicit identifier instead of a wildcard, no extra anythings on the end.  Importantly, make sure the correct team ID automatically shows up for the App Prefix.  Then enter the base identifier, such as com.mycompanyname.myappname
For the Provisioning Profile, set up a Distribution > Developer ID (aka Developer ID Application) profile. From the drop down you can then select your fully-qualified bundle identifier.

Yes I already did try the explicit identifier. It works just for the main target. But the other two targets I have created, with a System extension and a lib fail. Because they have the same BundleID + "." + "NAME OF THE TARGET", so the other two are not matching with the provisioning Profile

I believe you can use the same bundle identifier if each platform target is in a separate project.
